# Powershell - move folders and all its contents to another folder

Tags: powershell, file, directory, move

I have a folder H:\FAKTURA with a bunch of folders in it.
In the same folder I have a folder named "ARKIV".
I want to move all folders in this folder to the "ARKIV" folder.

I have the following but nothing happens, no errors, no moving of folders/files

```
 $current_logfiles = "H:\FAKTURA\"
 $destination = "H:\FAKTURA\ARKIV\"

 if ((Test-Path -Path $destination)) 
 {
     Move-Item -Path $current_logfiles -Destination $destination - 
     Exclude "H:\FAKTURA\ARKIV"  -force
 }
```

I got "Access to path "H:FAKTURA" is denied"
Is there something I am missing here..? I have full access to this folder, I can manually do this. And I am running powershell as Administrator too, but no success :(

[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all: Why not using robocopy? Second: Since `ARKIV` is a subfolder of the folder you want to copy from you have to make an exception for `ARKIV`.  `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: And BTW: In your if condition you check for a variable you did not define yet. At least not  in the code you show.

Comment: Does one of these threads help you further? ["powershell" move folder to subfolder](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpowershell%5D+move+folder+to+subfolder)

Comment: Have this - excluded ARKIV folder - but still nothing happens, no error though

$current_logfiles = H:\FAKTURA"
$new_logfiles = "H:\FAKTURA\ARKIV"
$excludes = 'ARKIV'

if (!(Test-Path -path $new_logfiles)) {
  Move-Item -Path $current_logfiles -Destination $new_logfiles -Exclude $excludes  -force
}

Comment: I thought this would be an easy task to move some folders :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stated that H:\FAKTURA\ARKIV which would mean that
Test-Path -path $destination would come back as True. Problem is that you then negate the result !(Test-Path -path $destination) which would come back as False and hence the If statement will not work. Remove the '!()'

Comment: Hi, now I got "access to path H:\Faktura is denied"


I have full access to this folder and can manuelly move/copy/delete files here

Comment: This is because you trying to copy H:\FAKTURA\ARKIV back onto itself. You have to exclude it from the command -Exclude "H:\FAKTURA\ARKIV"

Comment: Modified it like this to exclude the folder itself, but the same error - "access to path H:\FAKTURA" is denied



$current_logfiles = "H:\FAKTURA\"
$destination = "H:\FAKTURA\ARKIV\"

if ((Test-Path -Path $destination)) 
{
  Move-Item -Path $current_logfiles -Destination $destination -Exclude "H:\FAKTURA\ARKIV"  -force
}

Comment: Even If I just do this simple command I get the "access to path H:\Faktura is denied

Move-Item -Path "H:\FAKTURA" -Destination "H:\FAKTURA\ARKIV" -Exclude "H:\FAKTURA\ARKIV"

Comment: You can't move a folder to a position within itself, it does not make sense and hence you get the access denied error.